# How to get License for open source controls

Tags: authentication, license-key

I have developed few open source controls and want to have license for my control from any recognized authority like MIT. How can I get it ?
Any suggestion is greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to raise any request. You may check this to choose which type of licence you would like to use, "http://choosealicense.com". It also talks about how to apply a particular licence. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already uploaded my control on github. Now how can i add license into that? Do I need to only create a txt file and paste license terms in that ?

Comment: Yes you need to paste license terms in that. Create a text file (typically named LICENSE or LICENSE.txt) in the root of your source code and copy the text of the license into the file. Replace [year] with the current year and [fullname] with the name (or names) of the copyright holders.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any request to any license centre. Read more about licenses in [Open source licensing](https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/) article of Github Documentation.